# PHP form not saving information to SQL database

Tags: php, mysql, html

I'm currently working on a project that has a registration form that should theoretically work as far as I know for the registration but I can't seem to identify what I'm doing wrong.

The code below is the front-end section for the registration form

```
<form style="border: 3px solid #ddd; border-radius: 10px; padding: 10px;" class="uk-form-stacked js-register">

        <div class="uk-margin">
            <label class="uk-form-label" for="form-stacked-text"><b>Username:</b></label>
            <div class="uk-form-controls">
                <input id="user_name" style="border-radius: 10px;" class="uk-input" name="form-stacked-text" type="text" required='required' placeholder="Insert Username">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="uk-margin">
            <label class="uk-form-label" for="form-stacked-text"><b>Email:</b></label>
            <div class="uk-form-controls">
                <input id="user_email" class="uk-input" style="border-radius: 10px;" name="form-stacked-text" type="email" required='required' placeholder="Insert Email">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="uk-margin">
            <label class="uk-form-label" for="form-stacked-text"><b>Password:</b></label>
            <div class="uk-form-controls">
                <input id="user_pass" class="uk-input" style="border-radius: 10px;" name="user_pass" type="Password" required='required' placeholder="Insert Password">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="uk-margin">
            <label class="uk-form-label" for="form-stacked-text"><b>Confirm Password:</b></label>
            <div class="uk-form-controls">
                <input id="user_pass_check" class="uk-input" style="border-radius: 10px;" name="user_pass_check" type="Password" required='required' placeholder="Confirm Password">
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="uk-margin">
            <div class="uk-form-controls">
                <div class="captcha">

                    <div align="center" class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="-" data-callback="recaptcha_callback"></div>
                </div>
                <br>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="uk-margin uk-alert-danger js-error" style='display: none;'></div>

        <div class="uk-margin">
            <label><center>Already have an account? <a href='/~za1180x/comp1687/login.php'>login now!</a></center></label>
            <br>
            <center><button id="registerbtn" name="registerbtn" class="uk-button uk-button-default"  type="submit"><b>REGISTER</b></button></center>
        </div>

    </form>
```

The backend code responsible for submitting the information to the database is as follow

```
if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST')
{
    $return = [];
    $email = Filter::String( $_POST['user_email']);
    $password = Filter::String( $_POST['user_pass']);
    $username = Filter::String( $_POST['user_name']);

    $user_found = User::Find($email, $username);

    mysqli_report ( MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL);

    if($user_found) {
        // User exists
        // We can also check to see if they are able to log in.
        $return['error'] = "You already have an account";
        $return['is_logged_in'] = false;
    } else  {

        // User does not exist, add them now.
        $password = password_hash($_POST['password'], PASSWORD_DEFAULT);
        // make sure the user CAN be added AND is added.
        $addUser = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO users(user_name, user_email, user_pass) VALUES(:user_name, LOWER(:user_email), :user_pass)");
        $addUser->bindParam(':username', $username, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $addUser->bindParam(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $addUser->bindParam(':password', $password, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $addUser->execute();

        $user_id = $con->lastInsertId();

        $_SESSION['user_id'] = (int) $user_id;

        $return['is_logged_in'] = true;

        $return['redirect'] = 'C:\wamp64\www\index.php?message=welcome';


    }
    // return the proper information back to Javascript to redirect us.

    echo json_encode($return, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
} else {
    //Kill the script. Redirect the user.
    exit('Invalid URL');
}
```

The code below is the class that I've created that makes the connection for the database.

```
class DB {

    protected static $con;

    private function __construct(){
        try {

            self::$con = new PDO( 'mysql:charset=latin1;host=localhost;port=3306;dbname=webenterprise', 'root', ''); //change connection string
            self::$con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
            self::$con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_SILENT);
            self::$con->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_PERSISTENT, false );
            self::$con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);

        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo "Could not connect to database."; exit;
        }
    }


    public static function getConnection() {
        //If this instance has not been started, start it.
        if (!self::$con) {
            new DB();
        }
        //Return the writeable db connection
        return self::$con;
    }

   }
```

Comment: While this *may* work, you should not use SQL commands like this: `LOWER(:user_email)` on placeholders as they are not really what you would expect. Modify those strings outside of your prepare statement.

Comment: Have you checked your error logs?

Comment: How would I do that? and what would be wrong if I carried on using this method?

Comment: @JayBlanchard I don't seem to be getting errors on my log. Maybe my xedebug isn't set up properly.

Comment: `strtolower()` in PHP does the same thing, so `$addUser->bindParam(':email', strtolower($email), PDO::PARAM_STR);`

Comment: There are no errors in your web server's error logs?

Comment: In your insert you have `:user_name` and bind to `:username` - check your bind names!

Comment: You're using PDO. Turning on `mysqli` errors is not going to help.

Comment: : "It looks like you're writing your own ORM. Have you considered using one that's already written, tested, and widely supported like [RedBeanPHP](https://redbeanphp.com/), [Doctrine](http://www.doctrine-project.org/), [Propel](http://propelorm.org/) or
[Eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent)?"

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/master/authentication) built-in.

Comment: @tadman I'm unsure of what an ORM is, but would it be easy for me to transfer my current work to a framework like Laravel? (would this be similar to working with asp.net on visual studio?)

Comment: Good catch @NigelRen - all of the bind names are wrong.

Comment: @NigelRen  I changed them to appropriate terms now but it still doesn't seem to work. Got spot though.

Comment: @JayBlanchard, for some reason no errors come up in the console or anything

Comment: You're already writing an ORM, you just don't know it yet. An ORM is an object-oriented wrapper around your database and models. Laravel is just one option, there are many, each with their own approach to solving problems. These give you patterns to work from instead of having to invent things out of nothing. You can usually port over your functionality but you'll have to adapt for the proper context, in a framework usually [MVC style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model–view–controller).

Comment: Errors for this would not appear in the console. They would be in the error logs of your web server.

Answer (score 1):

I can see different problems:

- You don't have a `method` attribute in you form element (GET is the default method);
- You don't have an `action` attribute in you form element;
- Your `name` attributes in your form don't correspond with the `$_POST` variables you're using (maybe a mix up with ids?);
- You start your backend code with `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST')` but you're using `$_POST` variables after: you should use `if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')` instead.

Maybe I missed some.